# Syntax on PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've tried to write a PostgreSQL query but I've got the syntax screwed up. I think it is pretty clear what I'm trying to do just from seeing the way I've written it. Basically I have a `users` and an `invitations` table. For any `users` who have no password, I want to update their email address with the email address in the `invitations` table. I want to find the user by simply checking for `users` and `invitations` that have a matching first and last name.

```
UPDATE users
SET users.email = invitations.parent_email
WHERE users.encrypted_password = ''
AND invitations.first_name = users.first_name
AND invitations.last_name = users.last_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able specify the other table in a a FROM field, and then do the update/join that way.

```
UPDATE users
SET email = invitation.parent_email
FROM invitation 
WHERE users.encrypted_password = '' AND 
      users.first_name = invitation.first_name  AND 
      users.last_name = invitation.last_name AND
      users.email <> invitation.parent_email
```

Comment: should just be able to add that as another clause (edited answer)

Comment: I'm seeing the problem now. I had it wrong. I need something like a WHERE NOT EXISTS ... In some cases there are records in the users that have an email address already that is the same from the invitations table BUT for whatever reason the first and last name are not the same. The query is failing on duplicate email. For those I'd like to just skip them and move on.